# 'OrderSend' - wrong parameters count

Tags: metatrader4, metatrader5, mt

```
input double Risk = 10.0;   // Percentage for stop loss (10%)
input double Reward = 30.0; // Percentage for take profit (30% - 1:3 risk-reward ratio)
double contractSize = 1.0;  // Starting contract size

void OnStart()
{
    if (Period() != PERIOD_M5) // Check if the chart is not M5
    {
        Print("This EA is designed for the 5-minute (M5) chart only. Please apply it on an M5 chart.");
        return;
    }

    if (!PositionSelect("XAUUSD")) // Check if there's an open position
    {
        double stopLoss = NormalizeDouble(contractSize * Risk / 100.0, 2); // Calculate stop loss
        double takeProfit = NormalizeDouble(contractSize * Reward / 100.0, 2); // Calculate take profit

        // Place a market buy order with calculated stop loss and take profit
        OrderSend("XAUUSD", ORDER_TYPE_BUY, contractSize, SymbolInfoDouble("XAUUSD", SYMBOL_ASK), 10, 0, 0, "Buy Order", 0, clrBlue);
        OrderSend("XAUUSD", ORDER_TYPE_SELL, contractSize, SymbolInfoDouble("XAUUSD", SYMBOL_BID), 10, 0, stopLoss, takeProfit, 0, clrRed);
    }
}

void OnTick()
{
    // Add tick event logic here if needed
}

void OnTimer()
{
    // Add timer event logic here if needed
}

void OnTrade()
{
    if (PositionsTotal() == 0) // Check if all positions are closed
    {
        OnStart(); // Open a new trade after the previous one has been closed
    }
}
```

Every time I try to compile I get 'OrderSend' - wrong parameters count error. Can someone help me solve this issue? I am using MT5. I have tried changing the name but I would still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use the MQL4 (MetaTrader 4) `OrderSend` function in MQL5 (MetaTrader 5), this is why you are getting errors.

The way orders are placed differs greatly between MQL4 and MQL5.

I would suggest reading the following page which has worked examples.

[`OrderSend`](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/trading/ordersend)